Prove that the MLE for variance is consistent
Suppose $X_1, ..., X_n$ are independent random variables with expected value $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$:

I would like to show the
$$
\hat\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_i - \bar X_n\right)^2\quad \mbox{is consistent}
$$
So far I have been able to show that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\hat\sigma^2\right] =
\frac{n-1}{n} \sigma^2
$$
All the proofs I have seen for consistency rely on the continuous mapping theorem.
However, I think it should also be straightforward to show directly, that
$$
\hat\sigma^2\ \mbox{converges to}\ \sigma^2\ \mbox{in probability}
$$

I would appreciated any help.

From the expectation you computed, you can see that $\widehat{\sigma}^{2}$ is asymptotically unbiased for $\sigma^{2}$. If you compute its variance, and show that it goes to zero as $n \rightarrow \infty$, this is enough to say that it is a consistent estimator for $\sigma^{2}$.

Thank you for the solution!
